# Rails / Paperclip: How do I display images from S3 that have authenticated_read permissions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Using Rails 3.2.1 and Paperclip 2.6

I have Paperclip set to use s3 as storage. I would like to use `:s3_permissions => :authenticated_read`.

Before Paperclip updated to use `aws-sdk`, I used the [`paperclip-aws`](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/paperclip-aws/blob/master/lib/paperclip-aws.rb) gem that provides a helper for authenticated access.

Does Paperclip provide a similar helper? How do I access the images through an `image_tag` if they are set to `authenticated_read` in the absence of the `paperclip-aws` gem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an attachment configured like so:

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => 'MY-BUCKET',
  :s3_permissions => :authenticated_read,
  :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/aws.yml")
```

You can just call the #expiring_url method on your attachment:

```
record.attachment.expiring_url #=> "https..."
```

Here is the signature for #expiring_url:

```
def expiring_url(time = 3600, style_name = default_style)
```

This allows you to override the expiration time and specify what "style" or version you want a url for.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, you're missing a comma after `:authenticated_read` in your configuration example.

Comment: I actually have a problem with this because it doesn't default to the paperclip `:default_url` to display missing images. It just returns nil. I had to write a helper method that would check whether `:expiring_url` returns nil and use the regular url method if it does. This probably is a bug with paperclip.